# Convergence in r-mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of random variables such that
$X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in r-mean. I want to prove that, if $\lim_{n} c_{n} = c$, then $c_n X_n$ converges in r-mean to $cX$. I know that $\lim_{n} E[|X_n-X|^r] = 0$ and $\lim_{n} c_n = c$, but don't know how to prove that $\lim_n E[|c_n X_n - cX|^r]=0$.

Comment: Do you also have that $E[|X_n|^r] < \infty$.

Comment: no I dont have this condition

Answer (score 0):

In case $E[|X|^r] = \infty$, then the result is generally false. For example, let $X \sim \text{Cauchy}$ and $X_1=X_2=\ldots=X$. Clearly, $X_{n}$ converges in r-mean to $X$. However, by taking $c_n=1-n^{-1}$, note that, for every $n$, $E[|c_n X_n-cX|^r]=\infty$. Therefore, the result does not hold.

In case $E[|X|^r] < \infty$, then

\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n} E[|c_n X_n - cX|^r]
 &= \lim_{n} E[|c_n X_n -cX_n +cX_n -cX|^r] \\
 &\leq \lim_{n} (E[|c_n X_n-cX_n|^r]+E[|cX_n -cX|^r]) \\
 &= \lim_{n} ((c_n-c)^r E[|X_n|^r]+c^r E[|X_n-X|^r]) \\
 &= \lim_{n} (c_n-c)^r E[|X_n-X+X|^r] \\
 &\leq \lim_{n} (c_n-c)^r (E[|X_n-X|^r])+E[|X|^r]) \\
 &= 0
\end{align*}

That is, $\lim_{n}E[|c_n X_n - cX|^r]=0$.